# ASP.Net MVC Web Application render view async with Continuous Ping

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asynchronous, model-view-controller

I have a .NET Core MVC Web Application that has an input field, a submit button and an output text area which (I hope) does exactly what Command Prompt can do.

Everything seems good to me, but I have an issue at the View part when I run some commands that need times to execute, especially the continuous ping command: `ping 8.8.8.8 -t`. The View will not render until the Process is Closed!

Is there any way to make the View renders output line by line like Command Prompt while the Process still running? I think that I'll need a button to stop it manually.

I'm very new to this field. Every help will be appreciated!

Here is my `Controller`:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(HomeViewModel model)
{
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
    {
        WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
        FileName = "cmd.exe",
        Arguments = @"/C " + model.InputCommand,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true
    };

    Process process = new Process()
    {
        StartInfo = startInfo
    };

    try
    {
        process.Start();
        Task task = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GetOutputAsync(process));
        process.WaitForExit();
    }
    finally
    {
        if (!process.HasExited)
            process.Close();
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

My `GetOutputAsync` method:

```
private async Task GetOutputAsync(Process process)
{
    while (!process.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
        ViewData["Result"] += await process.StandardOutput.ReadLineAsync();
}
```

And finally, the `View`:

```
<style>
    .break-line {
        white-space: pre-line;
    }
</style>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.InputCommand, new { htmlAttributes = new { @type = "text", @class = "form-control" } })
        <div class="input-group-append">
            <input class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="submit" value="Run" />
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div class="card text-white bg-dark mb-6">
    <div class="card-header">Result</div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text break-line">@ViewData["Result"]</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does it work with ping 8.8.8.8 without the -t?

Comment: You could use Angular / React for updating the rendered view in real-time, outside of that ... you would need to move the call to kick off from javascript and update the html directly on the frontend.

Comment: @GregoryWilliamBryant Yes. I've to wait a little bit but the output is the same as command prompt (without line breaks, but I think I can deal with it later)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your problem is related to Task task = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GetOutputAsync(process));.   I would imagine that it would get the output when the process has stopped.  I.e. there is no output until the ping has been stoped progromaticly.  I may be wrong.   If I was approaching it from the hacky perspective  I would use "pint 8.8.8.8 -t >> log.txt" and then parse the log file.

Comment: Yes, you're right! The output only displays when the process has stopped and that is my problem. I've read about Websockets and look like it's quite complicated for me if there are no concrete examples. I'll take your approach as a backup plan.